# Casts required in unexpected places

Tags: scala, types

There are some cases in Scala when I need to use a cast, although I would say it is not strictly required. Consider the following program:

```java
abstract class A {
  type T <: F[T]
}

abstract class F[T <: F[T]] {
  def me: String
}

class B extends A {
  type T = TB
}

class TB extends F[TB] {
  def me = "It's me"
  def you = "It's you"
}

trait Operator[S <: A] extends Function[S#T,String]

object f1 extends Operator[A] {
  def apply(x: A#T) = x.me
}

object f2 extends Operator[B] {
  def apply(x: B#T) = x.you
}

object Driver {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val bi = new TB()
    println(f1(bi.asInstanceOf[A#T]))
    println(f2(bi))
  }
}
```

If I remove `asInstanceOf[A#T]` in the `main` method the code does not compile. However, I do not think the cast is really necessary. Actually, looking at the generated bytecode with `javap`, there is no occurrence of the `checkcast` instruction. Is this a limit of the Scala type-checker or there is something I am missing?

Comment: why not just have `def f` declared to accept an `F[_]` instead of a `A#T`?

Comment: In this case I could, but I probably over-simplified what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I modified the question to be more faithful to the real code.

Comment: I wasn't particularly surprised by your case here, as explained in my answer. But the failure for this expression is intriguing: `implicitly[B#T <:< A#T]`. I guess I'll need to check out the SLS...

Comment: I checked the SLS. It says "A type projection T#t conforms to U#t if
T conforms to U". Since B <: A, it should be able to prove B#T <: A#T.

Comment: It seems that, when trying to prove `B#T <: A#T`, the compiler first replaces `B#T` with `TB` and then get stuck (for what you explained in your answer). For example, even if you replace `val bi = new TB()` with `val bi: B#T = new TB()`, when you remove `asInstanceOf[A#T]` the error message you get is `found   : bi.type (with underlying type TB) required: A#T`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a limit of the type-checker, but it's a reasonable one. Consider what you're asking it to prove to show that `TB <: A#T`: that there's some subclass of `A` (let's call it `C`) for which `TB <: C#T` and `C#T` is concrete. Such a subclass exists (i.e., `B`), but would we necessarily want the compiler to search `A`'s entire hierarchy to find it?

Answer (score 2):

The specification is unsound; see https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7278 among others.